# How add telerik in project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I entered in work with Telerik RadControls. In web.config telerik set in many places. But can anyone give me algorithm how in new project asp.net (web application) in Visual Studio 2010 add dll? (dll library I have)

Comment: I'm sorry but the question isn't really clear to me. What are you trying to do? The (right) Telerik reference DLL's will automatically be added when you use a control or other component.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add the items to the toolbox so you can do Drag And Drop, do this:

1). Open Visual Studio

2). Open a new project (or existing)

3). Find your "toolbar" window in VS.

4). Right click in the tool bar white space (somewhere where there are no existing controls)

5). Click "Add Tab"

6). Name this tab "Telerik"

7). Now, right click again, and hit "Choose items"

8). A Window will pop open, you can select your Telerik DLL, and it will fill the tool box with 
all the controls you need.

You can then Drag and Drop these controls to your pages.
I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Telerik installed on your Visual Studio machine, but it is not currently part of your project, the easiest way to add the proper Telerik DLLs and web.config entries would be to go to the Telerik menu at the top of your Visual Studio, and select Convert to Telerik Web Site.